# Update and Insert in a Single Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains `pageid`, `department`, `position` and `active`. While updating, I have to update **active** column if `pageid` is already exists, if not I will insert a new row with the `pageid`.

I am getting pageid values through checkbox and my update query is like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO access_level (page_id, department, position, active) 
               VALUES (".$sn.", ".$department.", ".$position.", 1) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        department=VALUES(".$department."), 
        position=VALUES(".$position."), 
        active=VALUES(1)";
```

But everything is getting inserted twice in this case.

Where I am doing wrong? Can somebody guide me?

Comment: your primary key is not set

Comment: I have a column called id which is primary key here. But how do i use it in this query?  I cannot make pageid unique as for different departments it can have same page id

Comment: are you using auto increment for id?

Comment: Yes i am using autoincrement

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work for you:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO access_level (page_id, department, position, active) 
               VALUES (".$sn.", ".$department.", ".$position.", 1) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id),  
        active=VALUES(1)";
```

Comment: i tried this, But getting `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1)' at line 1 `
and the query is


**`INSERT INTO access_level (page_id, department, position, active) VALUES (1, 4, 4, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE aid=LAST_INSERT_ID(aid), active=VALUES('1')`. **I am not getting what